# Align equations in math mode with bullet points in itemize

Tags: align

I want to vertically align the equations I have in math mode with the bullet points.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item $$\tan(x+y) = \frac{\tan x + \tan y}{1-\tan x \tan y}$$
\item $$\tan(x-y) = \frac{\tan x - \tan y}{1+\tan x \tan y}$$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]
As you can see, the equation isn't exactly aligned with the bullet point. I don't want to put the equations in inline mode.

Comment: the code you posted does not produce the output that you show. (the bullets are aligned with the text)

Comment: I fixed it now, I meant for the equations to be in math mode.

Comment: ah you changed it after my first comment. `$$` is not latex you should use `\[` (but the output would be the same). Use inline mode but add `\displaystyle`  after the first `$` so it uses display style.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use inline math in display style:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item $\displaystyle \tan(x+y) = \frac{\tan x + \tan y}{1-\tan x \tan y}$
\item $\displaystyle \tan(x-y) = \frac{\tan x - \tan y}{1- +\tan x \tan y}$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi David, peraphs there is a fix typo in your code in the second formula. In fact there are two operators + and -.

Answer (score 2):

I add my option to get the bullets aligned with the formula and the text.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item{$\tan(x+y) = \dfrac{\tan x + \tan y}{1-\tan x \tan y};$\quad } this is the first formula.
    \item{$\tan(x-y) = \dfrac{\tan x - \tan y}{1 +\tan x \tan y};$\quad } this is the second formula.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This uses flalign to include a fake item on the left.  The `&&\hspace{\labelwidth}` on the right helps balance the equations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only
\newcommand{\fakeitem}{\makebox[\labelwidth][r]{\textbullet}}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
\fakeitem && \tan(x+y) &= \frac{\tan x + \tan y}{1-\tan x \tan y} &&\hspace{\labelwidth}\\[\itemsep]
\fakeitem && \tan(x-y) &= \frac{\tan x - \tan y}{1+\tan x \tan y}
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]